Čech simplicial complex contractible
For an open cover $(U_i)_{i\in I}$ of a topological space $X$ and a finite subset $E\subset I$ we write $U_E=\bigcap_{i\in E}U_i$.
A locally finite cover is called a good cover, if all $U_E$ are contractible.
Suppose this to be the case, then one defines a simplicial complex $S$ with vertex set $I$ and simplices are the finite sets $E\subset I$ with $U_E\ne\emptyset$.
My question is this: Suppose that $X$ is contractible, does it follow that $S$  is contractible?

This is a consequence of the following result in Hatcher’s introductory algebraic topology book. Your S is NU therein, and it is homotopy equivalent to X whenever it is paracompact.

Corollary 4G.3. If U is an open cover of a paracompact space X such
that every nonempty intersection of finitely many sets in U is
contractible, then X is homotopy equivalent to the nerve NU.


You might even be able to remove paracompactness from Hatcher's argument since we already know the cover is locally finite. Up to this type of details (and choice of language plus method of computation of the homotopy colimit), it is essentially the same proof that I gave: $X$ is the homotopy colimit of any open covering. I'm very grateful for the reference, and would not mind if this answer is accepted instead.

@R.vanDobbendeBruyn I don’t think you can get rid of paracompactness. It’s essentially the only way of getting an arrow out of X. At the end of your argument, you use that $X$ contractible implies $Sing(X)$ contractible, but in general they don’t have the same homotopy type because general topological spaces can be very pathological.

Right, that makes sense. So there is a subtle but important technical difference between the arguments: whether or not you apply $\operatorname{Sing}(-)$ before stating the homotopy colimit property. (Actually, they already differ on compact Hausdorff spaces — my favourite example is the Warsaw circle, for which $\operatorname{Sing}(X)$ is contractible, the shape is the circle, but $X$ is not homotopy equivalent to either.)

Paracompactness can at least be reduced to normality (which is equivalent to the numberability of all locally-finite open covers).

This is true, and follows from Lurie's version of the van Kampen theorem.
Indeed, in Prop. A.3.2 of Higher algebra, it is shown that $\operatorname{Sing}(X)$ is the homotopy colimit of $\operatorname{Sing}(U)$ taken over the subposet $T \subseteq \operatorname{Open}(X)$ consisting of opens $V$ contained in some $U_i$. Morally speaking, this says that $U \mapsto \operatorname{Sing}(U)$ is a cosheaf of spaces/anima/homotopy types/...(hosets??), in the $\infty$-categorical sense.
To compute the homotopy colimit, we first replace $T$ by $T^* = T \setminus \{\varnothing\}$, which does not change the colimit since $\varnothing$ is sent to $\varnothing$. Let $P$ be the poset of nonempty finite subsets of $I$, and let $Q = \{E \in P\ |\ U_E \neq \varnothing\}$. Note that $Q$ is the poset of simplices of the simplicial complex $S = (I,Q)$ to which we want to compare our answer.
Define the functor $F \colon Q^{\text{op}} \to T^*$ by $E \mapsto U_E$. Then $F$ is cofinal: by Joyal's version of Quillen's theorem A [HTT, Thm. 4.1.3.1] [Kerodon, Tag 02NY], we need to check that the comma category $(V \downarrow F)$ has contractible nerve for all $V \in T^*$. By hypothesis, $V$ is contained in some $U_i$, so $(V \downarrow F) \neq \varnothing$. Since the covering is locally finite, any point is contained in only finitely many $U_i$, so in particular $V$ is contained in only finitely many (here we use that we tossed out $V = \varnothing$). Then $J = \{i \in I\ |\ V \subseteq U_i\}$ gives an initial object in $(V \downarrow F)$, showing that $(V \downarrow F)$ is weakly contractible [Kerodon, Tag 02P2]. Thus, we may instead compute the homotopy colimit over $Q^{\text{op}}$.
Thus, $\operatorname{Sing}(X)$ is the homotopy colimit of $\operatorname{Sing}(U_E)$ over $Q^{\text{op}}$. This is just the constant functor $*$ on $Q^{\text{op}}$, since all $U_E$ for $E \in Q$ are assumed contractible. The homotopy colimit of a constant diagram $*$ indexed by a category $\mathscr C$ is the geometric realisation of the nerve of $\mathscr C$. On the other hand, the geometric realisation of the nerve of $Q$ is canonically identified with the barycentric subdivision of $S$, hence is homeomorphic to $S$.
Putting everything together, we get
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Sing}(X) &\simeq \underset{V \in T}{\operatorname{colim}} \operatorname{Sing}(V) \simeq \underset{V \in T^*}{\operatorname{colim}} \operatorname{Sing}(V) \simeq \underset{E \in Q^{\text{op}}}{\operatorname{colim}} \operatorname{Sing}(U_E) \simeq \underset{Q^{\text{op}}}{\operatorname{colim}} * \\
&\simeq \lvert N(Q^{\text{op}}) \rvert \cong \lvert N(Q) \rvert \cong S.
\end{align*}
If $X$ is contractible, then so is $\operatorname{Sing}(X)$, hence so is $S$. $\square$
